# Use JOIN with OFFSET in the same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I use `JOIN` with `OFFSET`?

I commented out to rows that produce error `incorrect syntax near inner`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPagination] -- ORDER BY id
    @PageNumber INT,
    @PageSize   INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      
        Emp.id, Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary],  
        Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age  --, Rol.[name] as Role
    FROM        
        [dbo].tblEmployees5m Emp
    ORDER BY    
        id
        -- INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblRoles] Rol ON Emp.roleId = Rol.id
        OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY 
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your `Order By` position is incorrect.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPagination] -- ORDER BY id
  @PageNumber INT,
  @PageSize   INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age  --, Rol.[name] as Role
    FROM        [dbo].tblEmployees5m    Emp
    inner join    [dbo].[tblRoles]        Rol
    ON            Emp.roleId = Rol.id
    ORDER BY    Emp.id
    OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
END
```